# Position: relative vs Transform: translate

Tags: css

For example if we would like to move element up on 50px both examples above kind of work

**Example 1**

```
position: relative;
top: -50px;
```

**Example 2**

```
transform: translateY(-50px);
```

Can you please explain possible difference in future behavior or maybe some nuances that exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example 1

- can be used in normal case
- supported by almost every browser - don't need to rewrite for other browsers

Example 2

- can be used for animations - using transform you can rotate object in three dimensions
- limited browser support (requires CSS3 so not early versions of IE nor Opera Mini)
- combined with using delay, you can animate rotation