# is there a way to to move element horizontal that contains margin: 0 auto with extra pixel to the left or right?

Tags: html, css

If you want a box centred with margin: 0 auto, but you want to slightly adjust its position by few pixel. is there a way? In another words content centred plus x pixel to the left/right?

I know I can add left: x. But that would not do what I want, I want to make sure the element is centered with only few pixel to the left. if I adjust jsut the left element without having it centered. it could ended up being in different location in different screen sizes.

CSS

```
.test{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*Plus code for x pixel to left/right.*/
}
```

Comment: Yes there is..just use this rules : position: relative; left:xx; right:xx; top:xx; bottom:xx; Use as you wish... Check this out..play with it - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/367/

Comment: true but then that will vary in different screens. I want to make sure the element is centered, with only few pixel to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using translate property

```css
.test{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*Plus code for x pixel to left/right.*/
    background:red;
    
    transform:translateX(10px);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: You mind explaining what transform and translate x does? or link a good tutorial

Comment: [css transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=a]) modifies can modify your element space, rotations scale...

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and this result - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/368/

Comment: @Luis P A ahh  I see waht you meant, I thought you meant to delete margin: 0 auto, and add left/right elements only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335370/position-relative-vs-transform-translate

Comment: @Luke, that was my point, maintain the center and add a new rule (left or right)...thanks for you feedback

Comment: @RenzoCC... now you can see what is the best answer :P

Comment: Just a few...not a animation, not for rotation, and browser support ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using position:relative and a negative value on 'left' or 'right' property. Look at this snippet I made.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  width:50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```